# Docker external database mapping

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, mariadb

I have cloned 'knowage' BI tool to my local cetnos 7 server and successfully ran the docker containers. My challenge is in connecting to a mariadb database that is in the Host machine! I want the knowage container to access that database in the Host machine. below is my server.xml file for the connection configs used by knowage..

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

<Resource name="jdbc/datasource" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mariadb://ip-addr:3306/datasource"
      username="beberu"
      password="***********"
      maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
      maxWait="-1"/>
```

```
            <!-- KNOWAGE -->
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/knowage" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://1$
```

```
<Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="$

<ResourceLink global="jdbc/datasource" name="jdbc/datasource" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ip address of the `docker0` interface in the place of 10.66.110.7.

You can get the ip address using this command.

```
$ ip addr show docker0
```

In the result use the ip after, inet.